# Mouse over events for links and nodes in d3.js should display texts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

JSON Data on HTML page is as follows:

```
   var IDData = JSON.stringify([["node/105173", "node/38180995", "Agent", "Customer", "1379644.0", 1, 264.0, "1374903"], ["node/1061", "node/21373542", "Agent", "Customer", "530848.0", 1, 3000.0, "529502"]....]
```

The length of the array of array varies but but positioning of elements inside it is always the same.

Below is my d3.js code:

```
function createNodes (IDData) {
   var nodes = [{group:1, group: 1}]; 
   var links = [];
   IDData.forEach(function(item){
   nodes.push({id: item, group: 1})
   links.push({source: item, target: item, value: 1}) // ;
  });  

  var d3GraphData = {
     nodes: nodes,
     links: links,
     startnodetype: startnodetype, //
     endnodetype: endnodetype,    right way to pass them to makeGraph()?

     PayTime: PayTime,
     TXN_COUNT: TXN_COUNT,
     Total_Amt: Total_Amt,
     SendTime: SendTime        //

  }
return d3GraphData;
 };


function makeGraph (selector, d3GraphData) {
    var svg = d3.select(selector),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

 var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
 var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

 var link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(d3GraphData.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); })
    .on("mouseover",mouse_link);  // calling mouseover function for links

 var node = svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "nodes")
     .selectAll("circle")
     .data(d3GraphData.nodes)
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("r", 5)
     .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
     .call(d3.drag()
     .on("start", dragstarted)
     .on("drag", dragged)
     .on("end", dragended)
)
 .on("mouseover",mouse_node);   //calling the mouseover function for nodes

  node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

 simulation
   .nodes(d3GraphData.nodes)
   .on("tick", ticked);

 simulation.force("link")
   .links(d3GraphData.links);

function ticked() {
  link
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

 node
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

      }

 function dragstarted(d) {
     if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
     d.fx = d.x;
     d.fy = d.y;
       }

 function dragged(d) {
   d.fx = d3.event.x;
   d.fy = d3.event.y;
     }

 function dragended(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
       d.fx = null;
       d.fy = null;
 }

 function mouse_node() {// function to handle mouse_over events on nodes
         d3.select(this).transition()
              .style("left", "20px")
              .style("top", "20px")
              .attr("r",30)
              .style("fill","lightsteelblue")
              .text(d.startnodetype or d.endnodetype); //how do I select the nodetype depending on whether it is the start node or end node?

 function mouse_link(){/// mouse over event on links
       d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration(750)
            .style("left", "20px")
            .style("top", "20px")
            .attr("r",30)
            .style("fill","lightsteelblue")
            .text(d.PayTime)
            .text(d.TXN_COUNT)
            .text(d.Total_Amt)
            .text(d.Send_Time)  // right way to display the texts?




$(document ).ready(function() {
    console.log(IDData);
    var galData = JSON.parse(IDData);
    var startnodes = [];
    var endnodes = [];
    var nodetype1 = [];
    var nodetype2 = [];
    var PayTime = [];
    var TXN_COUNT = [];
    var Total_Amt = [];
    var SendTime = [];

galData.map(function(e,i){
   startnodes.push(e[0]);
   endnodes.push(e[1]);
   nodetype1.push(e[2]);
   nodetype1.push(e[3]);
   PayTime.push(e[4]);
   TXN_COUNT.push(e[5]);
   Total_Amt.push(e[6]);
   SendTime.push(e[7]);
     });

  var final_data createNodes(startnodes,endnodes,startnodetype,endnodetype,PayTime,TXN_COUNT,Total_Amount,SendTime);                           
  makeGraph("#Network_graph",final_nodes)

  });
```

Also , in my HTML page  a div to display the relevant texts when node or links are clicked:

```
    <div id="graph"></div>
    < div id = "text"</div?
```

Is  text a better way or tool tip? and how to connect this div to d3.js? I thought of text because I want it to be part of the HTML body.

I have never worked in javascript or d3.js before. Apologies if too much code is pasted.I did read up and understand how and where to use the event functions. But still not sure if above is the right way to implement it. Especially , when the JSON data from the source is not of fixed size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is text a better way or tool tip?

This is opinion based and better not addressed at SO.

> how to connect this div to d3.js?

Since your `<div>`s have an ID, it's just a matter of changing its content on the `click` event.

This is a very basic demo showing it. First, we select the div:

```
var div = d3.select("#text");
```

And we set a `click` event to the circles, using the first argument in the anonymous function to access the data:

```
circles.on("click", function(d){
    div.html("This circle is named " + d.name);
});
```

So, you have to write a similar code for your nodes and links.

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [{name: "foo", size: 20, colour: "blue"},
            {name: "bar", size: 30, colour: "green"},
            {name: "baz", size: 15, colour: "red"}];

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 100);

var div = d3.select("#text");

var circles = svg.selectAll(".circles")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", function(d,i){ return 50 + i*100})
  .attr("r", function(d){ return d.size})
  .attr("fill", function(d){ return d.colour});

circles.on("click", function(d){
 div.html("This circle is named " + d.name);
  });
```

```css
circle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">Click the circle to see its name</div>
```

**PS**: You said *"display the relevant texts when node or links are clicked"*, but your question's title says *"mouse over"*. The above demo uses `click`, but it's the same principle for `mouseover`. Check the demo using `mouseover`:

```js
var data = [{name: "foo", size: 20, colour: "blue"},
            {name: "bar", size: 30, colour: "green"},
            {name: "baz", size: 15, colour: "red"}];

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 100);

var div = d3.select("#text");

var circles = svg.selectAll(".circles")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", function(d,i){ return 50 + i*100})
  .attr("r", function(d){ return d.size})
  .attr("fill", function(d){ return d.colour});

circles.on("mouseover", function(d){
 div.html("This circle is named " + d.name);
  }).on("mouseout", function(){
  div.html("Hover the circle to see its name");
  });
```

```css
circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">Hover the circle to see its name</div>
```